# Como guardar imagen modificada en sqlserver c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms, picturebox

soy nuevo en programacion y estoy haciendo un pequeño software para un amigo que es dentista, entonces quiero guardar cada modificación que el haga en la imagen, y que cuando se llame ese registro del paciente ahí esten las modificaciones viejas y cuando haga nuevas tambien se guarden.

anexo la imagen de lo que desee hacer. 
Al precionar el boton guardar que esos dibujos o lineas hechas se guarden en la base de datos, y cuando se llame ese paciente cargue esa imagen con esos trabajos hechos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español. Te recomiendo que te des un tour [tour] para que te veas cómo funciona esta comunidad y de paso ganes tu primera medalla. No basta con decir necesito x o y, la idea es que compartas dudas o preguntas concretas y que aportes parte del código que hayas escrito para intentar llegar a una solución. Puedes ver estos links de interés: [ask] y [repro]. Por favor [edit] tu pregunta y agregar mayor info.

Comment: Hola @hb03, no es muy recomendable guardar las imágenes en la base de datos. Lo que te sugiero es que  solo guardes el nombre y lo llames cuando lo necesites.Siempre que formules una pregunta por favor coloca lo que tienes desarrollado para poderte ayudar mejor. Gracias

Comment: Hola @hb03 yo hice un odontograma anteriormente y guardaba los estados en cada registro para despues consultarlos y dibujarlos según sea necesario.

Comment: Nos puedes compartir un poco más del código y como tienes la base de datos para darte algún consejo

Answer (score 0):

Para guardar la imagen que acaba de modificar el usuario, mi recomendación sería guardar en la base de datos en una ubicación la ruta del archivo.

`CREATE TABLE Odontogramas(
ExpedienteId int,
RutaArchivo nvarchar(max)
);`

Ya que tengas el `ExpedienteId` puedes guardar el archivo en una ruta especifica haciendo referencia a ese registro, el código para obtener la imagen y guardarla en el dispositivo sería el siguiente:

```
string CarpetaBase = $@"C:\Odontogramas";
string RutaArchivo = Path.Combine(CarpetaBase, $"odontograma_{ExpedienteId}");
using (var m = new MemoryStream())
{
    pictureBox1.Image.Save(m, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    var b = m.ToArray();
    File.WriteAllBytes(RutaArchivo, b);
}
```

Y por último se ingresa esta información a la base de datos verificando si es un nuevo registro o si se está actualizando la información.

```
string queryString =
@"
IF(EXISTS(SELECT ExpedienteId FROM Odontogramas WHERE ExpedienteId = @id))
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Odontogramas SET RutaArchivo = @ruta
        WHERE ExpedienteId = @id
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Odontogramas (ExpedienteId, RutaArchivo)
        VALUES(@id, @ruta);
    END";
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
            connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
        queryString, connection);
    command.Parameters.Clear();
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ExpedienteId);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ruta", RutaArchivo);
    connection.Open();
    int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```